# Need Help Finding Permission Needed for Entity Reference Content Type field

Tags: views, nodes

I've got a content type called 'resources' in my drupal 7 site. I have authors who have permission to create new resources and edit all the fields.

However, I have recently added a new 'entity reference' field to 'resources'. This field is a select list and the options are 'none' (the default) or 'on the home page'. The authors can SEE this field when they edit or create a new resource, but the only option available to them is 'none'. However, as an admin I can see both 'none' or 'on the home page'. When I select 'on the home page' it puts that particular resource into a VIEW block on the home page of the site. I'd like authors to be able to do this themselves.

I've tried giving authors the permission to edit all Views settings (just to see what would happen) and it didn't help.

Here's how I have it setup:

**Views Block:**

- Access permission, view published content
- Pager: display 1 item
- Relationships: entity reference: GS Resource
  (identifier: content entity reference from field_gs_resource_2 - require this relationship)

**Content type GS Resource:**

- Entity reference - select list (name: field_gs_resource)
- custom permissions: admin/author all have all permissions
- target type: content
- Mode: simple; target bundle: GS resource

**Content type Resource:** (for embedding the field into the main content type used when creating resources)

- Entity reference - select list (name: field_gs_resource_2)
- custom permissions: admin/author all have all permissions
- target type: content
- Mode: simple; target bundle: GS resource

Does anyone have any idea how to give the author the permission they need to edit this field when creating a new resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this one. It was the permission 'Bypass content access control' under 'Node'. I gave this permission to the one user role and then removed 'add content' from the shortcut bar so they could only use the link I gave them to create the one specific content type I want them to create.